# files not in docker workdir azure web app

Tags: azure, docker, file, dockerfile, containers

I created an image with this dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

my workdir is /usr/src/app, and I copy my project using COPY . .
I created a container and uploaded it to azure web service. I search in the kudu bash for the workdir, or any other file, and I cant find it. The container runs and does what it should, but the files are no where to be seen. how can I find it?

Comment: What do you mean by "created a container and uploaded it to azure web service"? Container is a running install, how can you upload it? Do you want to say, created an image and uploaded it azure container registry?

Comment: yes, you are right. thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your question, the first thing you need to know is that the kudu bash is not in the system that your container. They are two different systems. So it's obvious you cannot find your files in it. And if you want to connect to your container, you need to [enable the SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh) in your container and SSH into it, then you can find the files in the working directory.